# Did I come up with new sort algorithm, or does it already exist?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, computer-science, mergesort

I am trying to make new way for merge sort to reduce space to `O(log(n))` and reduce best case for `O(n)` while keep having stability and worst case of `(n Log(n))`

C# code:

```
public static void mergeSortMineInit(List<int> list)
{
    int n = list.Count;
    int width = 32;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i += width)
    {
        insertionSortModified(list, i, Math.Min(i + width, n));
    }

    while (width <= n)
    {
        int width2T = 2 * width;

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i += width2T)
        {
            merge(list, i, Math.Min(i + width, n - 1), Math.Min(i + width2T, n));
        }

        width = width2T;
    }
}

public static void insertionSortModified(List<int> arr, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    for (int i = startIndex + 1; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        int key = arr[i];
        int j = i - 1;

        while (startIndex <= j && key < arr[j])
        {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j--;
        }

        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

public static void merge(List<int> list, int start, int mid, int end)
{
    int? amountOfItems = kthElementAmount(
      list: list,
      start: start,
      midEnd: mid,
      mid: mid,
      end: end
    );

    if (amountOfItems == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    int newMidIndex = mid - amountOfItems.Value;
    int i = newMidIndex;
    int j = mid;

    for (; j < mid + amountOfItems; i++, j++)
    {
        int temp = list[j];
        list[j] = list[i];
        list[i] = temp;
    }

    merge(list, start, newMidIndex, mid); //m-amount,m
    merge(list, mid, mid + amountOfItems.Value, end); //amount,n
}

public static int? kthElementAmount(List<int> list, int start, int midEnd, int mid, int end, bool isNormal = true)
{
    int list1Size = midEnd - start;
    int list2Size = end - mid;

    if (Math.Min(list1Size, list2Size) <= 16)
    {
        miniSort(list: list, start: start, mid: mid, end: end);
        return null;
    }

    if (list1Size > list2Size)
    {
        return kthElementAmount(list: list, start: mid, midEnd: end, mid: start, end: midEnd, isNormal: false);
    }

    int k = isNormal ? list1Size : list2Size;

    int low = 0;
    int high = list1Size;

    Func<int?, int?, bool> l1r2Func;
    Func<int?, int?, bool> l2r1Func;

    if (isNormal)
    {
        l1r2Func = (l1, r2) => l1 == null || r2 == null || l1 <= r2;
        l2r1Func = (l2, r1) => l2 == null || r1 == null || l2 < r1;
    }
    else
    {
        l1r2Func = (l1, r2) => l1 == null || r2 == null || l1 < r2;
        l2r1Func = (l2, r1) => l2 == null || r1 == null || l2 <= r1;
    }

    while (low <= high)
    {
        int cut = (low + high) >> 1;
        int cut1 = cut + start;
        int cut2 = (k - cut) + mid;

        int? l1Index = cut1 == start ? null : cut1 - 1;

        int? l1 = l1Index == null ? null : list[l1Index.Value]; //MIN_VALUE
        int? r1 = cut1 == midEnd ? null : list[cut1]; //MAX_VALUE

        //
        int? l2Index = cut2 == mid ? null : cut2 - 1;
        int? l2 = l2Index == null ? null : list[l2Index.Value]; //MIN_VALUE
        int? r2 = cut2 == end ? null : list[cut2]; //MAX_VALUE

        bool l1r2Bool = l1r2Func(l1, r2);
        bool l2r1Bool = l2r1Func(l2, r1);

        if (l1r2Bool && l2r1Bool)
        {
            if (isNormal)
            {
                return l2Index == null ? null : l2Index - mid + 1; //amount
            }
            else
            {
                return l1Index == null ? null : l1Index - start + 1; //amount
            }
        }
        else if (!l1r2Bool)
        {
            high = cut - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            low = cut + 1;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Incorrect input??!!");
}

public static void miniSort(List<int> list, int start, int mid, int end)
{
    List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
    if (start > mid)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (end - mid < mid - start)
    {
        //second smaller
        for (int j = mid; j < end; j++)
        {
            tempList.Add(list[j]);
        }

        int listIndex = mid - 1;
        int tempIndex = tempList.Count - 1;

        int counter = end - 1;

        for (; start <= listIndex && 0 <= tempIndex; counter--)
        {
            if (tempList[tempIndex] < list[listIndex])
            {
                list[counter] = list[listIndex];
                listIndex--;
            }
            else
            {
                list[counter] = tempList[tempIndex];
                tempIndex--;
            }
        }

        for (; start <= listIndex; counter--)
        {
            list[counter] = list[listIndex];
            listIndex--;
        }

        for (; 0 <= tempIndex; counter--)
        {
            list[counter] = tempList[tempIndex];
            tempIndex--;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //first smaller
        for (int i = start; i < mid; i++)
        {
            tempList.Add(list[i]);
        }

        int tempListSize = tempList.Count;

        int listIndex = mid;
        int tempIndex = 0;

        int counter = start;

        for (; listIndex < end && tempIndex < tempListSize; counter++)
        {
            if (tempList[tempIndex] <= list[listIndex])
            {
                list[counter] = tempList[tempIndex];
                tempIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                list[counter] = list[listIndex];
                listIndex++;
            }
        }

        for (; listIndex < end; counter++)
        {
            list[counter] = list[listIndex];
            listIndex++;
        }

        for (; tempIndex < tempListSize; counter++)
        {
            list[counter] = tempList[tempIndex];
            tempIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Test on list of 3000000 item

**Random elements**

- Top Down Merge Sort:  0:00:01.322298
- Bottom Up Merge Sort: 0:00:01.794660
- MergeSort Mine:       0:00:03.539161
- Heap Sort:            0:00:04.485955

**Sorted elements**

- Top Down Merge Sort:  0:00:00.448717
- Bottom Up Merge Sort: 0:00:00.682326
- Merge Sort Mine:      0:00:00.105623
- Heap Sort:            0:00:01.298882

Comment: Might be better off posted on [cs.se]. Seems to be a combination of insertion sort and merge sort, although as far as I understand it's actually better to do insertion sort only on *small* inputs. Which is why introspective sort does that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort. Another common efficiency is to switch to network sort at less than say 5 or 6 items.

Comment: I will add Computer Science. thanks.
Insertion sort just to skip small merge from (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32), we can delete insertion sort with some adjustments and it will still working